# Adding licence field to WSO2 API in API manager

Tags: api, wso2

I have the need to add a licence field to the APIs published by the API manager.

It does not seems to be any extension point beyond the api.rxt file in the resource folder.
If I modify the file and run the application the carbon app correctly show the added field, but nor the publishe nor the store are able to get the field and there is no way to get it also with REST APIs since it calls a method of a class that (in later versions) outputted fields positionally.

Is it possible to add the field, without running the risk of crashing the API Manager?

Which is the correct way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This change cannot be done without modifying the code. When an API is created from the Publisher app, it gets stored in the registry. The api.txt you modified, only defines the structure of this stored artifact. It may add a new field to the artifact, but to correctly populate that field, you need to modify several methods in APIProviderHostObject and APIProviderImpl + several Jaggery scripts.